# ARKit and RealityKit - ARSessionDelegate is retaining 14 ARFrames

Tags: swiftui, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, apple-vision

I am classifying images per frame from ARSession delegate by Vision framework and CoreML in an Augmented Reality app, with ARKit and RealityKit. While processing a `frame.capturedImage` I am not requesting another `frame.capturedImage` for performance.

The camera is not giving smooth experience, it gets stuck time to time. Seems like a frame loss.

And I am getting this Warning:

```
[Session] ARSession <0x122cc3710>: ARSessionDelegate is retaining 14 ARFrames. This can lead to future camera frames being dropped.
```

My Codes:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit
import CoreML

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {

    var errorFunc: ()->Void
    var frameUpdateFunc: ()->Void
    @Binding var finalLabel:String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.planeDetection = [.horizontal,.vertical]
        config.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsSceneReconstruction(.mesh){
            config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
        }
        arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator
        arView.session.run(config)

       
        context.coordinator.myView = arView
        return arView
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(finalLabel: $finalLabel, self, funct: self.errorFunc, frameUpdateFunc: self.frameUpdateFunc)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {
        var objectDetectionService = ObjectDetectionService()
        var myView:ARView?
        @Binding var finalLabel:String
        var parent: ARViewContainer
        var efunc:()->Void
        var frameUpdateFunc:()->Void
        
        var isLoopShouldContinue = true
        var lastLocation: SCNVector3?
        
        
        //let model = try? MobileNetV2(configuration: .init())
        private let classifier = VisionClasifier(mlModel: try? MobileNetV2(configuration: .init()).model)
        private var currentBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
        init(finalLabel:Binding<String>,_ arView: ARViewContainer,funct: @escaping ()->Void, frameUpdateFunc:@escaping ()->Void) {
            parent = arView
            self.efunc = funct
            self.frameUpdateFunc = frameUpdateFunc
            _finalLabel = finalLabel
        }
        
        func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            //print("Error Tanvir: ",error)
            self.efunc()
        }
        
        func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
            if isLoopShouldContinue{
                self.classifyFrame(currentFrame: frame)
            }
            
            
            let transform = SCNMatrix4(frame.camera.transform)
            let orientation = SCNVector3(-transform.m31, -transform.m32, transform.m33)
            let location = SCNVector3(transform.m41, transform.m42, transform.m43)
            let currentPositionOfCamera = orientation + location
            
            if let lastLocation = lastLocation {
                let speed = (lastLocation - currentPositionOfCamera).length()
                isLoopShouldContinue = speed < 0.0025
            }
            lastLocation = currentPositionOfCamera

        }
        
        
        
//         When ARKit detects a new anchor, it will add it to the ARSession
//             Whenever there is a newly added ARAnchor, you will get that anchor here.
//             In this short tutorial, we will target the ARPlaneAnchor, and use the information stored
//             in that anchor for visualization.
            func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
                guard let myView = myView else {
                    return
                }
                for anchor in anchors {
                    if anchor is ARPlaneAnchor {
                        let planeAnchor = anchor as! ARPlaneAnchor
                        //addPlaneEntity(with: planeAnchor, to: myView)
                    }
                }
            }

            // ARKit will automatically track and update the ARPlaneAnchor.
            // We use that anchor to update the `skin` of the plane.
            func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
                guard let myView = myView else {
                    return
                }

                for anchor in anchors {
                    if anchor is ARPlaneAnchor {
                        let planeAnchor = anchor as! ARPlaneAnchor
                        //updatePlaneEntity(with: planeAnchor, in: myView)
                    }
                }
            }

            // When ARKit remove an anchor from the ARSession, you will get the removed
            // anchor here.
            func session(_ session: ARSession, didRemove anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
                guard let myView = myView else {
                    return
                }
                for anchor in anchors {
                    if anchor is ARPlaneAnchor {
                        let planeAnchor = anchor as! ARPlaneAnchor
                        //removePlaneEntity(with: planeAnchor, from: myView)
                    }
                }
            }
        
        func addAnnotation(rectOfInterest rect: CGRect, text: String,width:Float,height:Float) {
            let point = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
            print("point:", point)
            
            //let scnHitTestResults = myView.hitTest(point,
                                                     // options: [SCNHitTestOption.searchMode: SCNHitTestSearchMode.all.rawValue])
            //guard !scnHitTestResults.contains(where: { $0.node.name == BubbleNode.name }) else { return }
            
            let raycastResult = myView!.raycast(from: point, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any)
            
//            guard let raycastQuery = myView!.raycastQuery(from: point,
//                                                            allowing: .existingPlaneInfinite,
//                                                            alignment: .horizontal),
//                  let raycastResult = myView.session.raycast(raycastQuery).first else { return }
            guard let raycastResult = raycastResult.first else{
                print("raycast result failed")
                return
                
            }
            let anchorExists = myView!.scene.anchors.contains(where: {$0.name == text})
            guard anchorExists == false else{
                print("anchor Already exists")
                return
            }
            let position = raycastResult.worldTransform.columns.3
            let myEntity = create2dEntity(with: position, boundingBox: rect, raycastResult: raycastResult,width:width ,height:height)
            let planeAnchorEntity = AnchorEntity()
            planeAnchorEntity.name = text
            planeAnchorEntity.position = simd_make_float3(position)


            planeAnchorEntity.addChild(myEntity)
            
            // Finally, add the entity to scene.
            myView!.scene.addAnchor(planeAnchorEntity)
            print("anchor added: ", planeAnchorEntity.name)

        }
        
        
        func classifyFrame(currentFrame:ARFrame){
            //let currentImageName = photos[currentIndex]
            
            // 2
            
            // 3
            
            
            print("inside Classify")
            //print("CurrentBuffer", currentBuffer)
            guard self.currentBuffer == nil else {
                //print("CurrentBuffer: ",currentBuffer)
                //self.finalLabel = "current buffer problem"
                return
            }
            
            self.currentBuffer = currentFrame.capturedImage
            
//            guard let model = self.model else {
//                return "Model not Found."
//            }
            
            let img = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: currentFrame.capturedImage)
            let cgImage = convertCIImageToCGImage(inputImage: img)
            guard let cgImage = cgImage else{
                print("can not convert CGImage")
                self.finalLabel = "can not convert CGImage"
                return
            }
            
            objectDetectionService.detect(on: .init(pixelBuffer: currentFrame.capturedImage)) { [weak self] result in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    self.finalLabel = response.classification.description
                    print("Real Width: ",response.boundingBox.width)
                    let rectOfInterest = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(
                        response.boundingBox,
                        Int(self.myView!.bounds.width),
                        Int(self.myView!.bounds.height))
                    
                    self.addAnnotation(rectOfInterest: rectOfInterest, text: response.classification.description,width: Float(response.boundingBox.width),height: Float(response.boundingBox.height))
                    
                    
                    print("Success:",response.classification.description)
                    self.currentBuffer = nil
                
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.finalLabel = "Detection Failed"
                    print("Detection failure: ",error.localizedDescription)
                    self.currentBuffer = nil
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        

    }
    
        
    
    
}

func convertCIImageToCGImage(inputImage: CIImage) -> CGImage? {
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(inputImage, from: inputImage.extent) {
        return cgImage
    }
    return nil
}

// The ARPlaneAnchor contains the information we need to create the `skin` of the plane.
func addPlaneEntity(with anchor: ARPlaneAnchor, to view: ARView) {
    
    let planeAnchorEntity = AnchorEntity(.plane([.any],
                                    classification: [.any],
                                    minimumBounds: [0.01, 0.01]))
    let planeModelEntity = createPlaneModelEntity(with: anchor)

    // Give Entity a name for tracking.
    planeAnchorEntity.name = anchor.identifier.uuidString + "_anchor"
    planeModelEntity.name = anchor.identifier.uuidString + "_model"
    
    // Add ModelEntity as a child of AnchorEntity.
    // AnchorEntity handles `position` of the plane.
    // ModelEntity handles the `skin` of the plane.
    planeAnchorEntity.addChild(planeModelEntity)
    
    // Finally, add the entity to scene.
    view.scene.addAnchor(planeAnchorEntity)
}

func create2dEntity(with position: simd_float4, boundingBox: CGRect, raycastResult:ARRaycastResult, width:Float,height:Float ) -> ModelEntity{
    var planeMesh: MeshResource
    var color: UIColor
    print("horizotal plane")
    color = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    print("Constant width: 0.1 but BoundingBox Width: ",boundingBox.width)
    planeMesh = .generatePlane(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
    return ModelEntity(mesh: planeMesh, materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: color, roughness: 0.25, isMetallic: false)])
}

func createPlaneModelEntity(with anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) -> ModelEntity {
    var planeMesh: MeshResource
    var color: UIColor
    
    if anchor.alignment == .horizontal {
        print("horizotal plane")
        color = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        planeMesh = .generatePlane(width: anchor.extent.x, depth: anchor.extent.z)
    } else if anchor.alignment == .vertical {
        print("vertical plane")
        color = UIColor.yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        planeMesh = .generatePlane(width: anchor.extent.x, height: anchor.extent.z)
    } else {
        fatalError("Anchor is not ARPlaneAnchor")
    }
    
    return ModelEntity(mesh: planeMesh, materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: color, roughness: 0.25, isMetallic: false)])
}

func removePlaneEntity(with anchor: ARPlaneAnchor, from arView: ARView) {
    guard let planeAnchorEntity = arView.scene.findEntity(named: anchor.identifier.uuidString+"_anchor") else { return }
    arView.scene.removeAnchor(planeAnchorEntity as! AnchorEntity)
}

func updatePlaneEntity(with anchor: ARPlaneAnchor, in view: ARView) {
    var planeMesh: MeshResource
    guard let entity = view.scene.findEntity(named: anchor.identifier.uuidString+"_model") else { return }
    let modelEntity = entity as! ModelEntity

    if anchor.alignment == .horizontal {
        planeMesh = .generatePlane(width: anchor.extent.x, depth: anchor.extent.z)
    } else if anchor.alignment == .vertical {
        planeMesh = .generatePlane(width: anchor.extent.x, height: anchor.extent.z)
    } else {
        fatalError("Anchor is not ARPlaneAnchor")
    }
    
    modelEntity.model!.mesh = planeMesh
}

import SceneKit

extension SCNVector3 {
    func length() -> Float {
        return sqrtf(x * x + y * y + z * z)
    }
}

func -(l: SCNVector3, r: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3Make(l.x - r.x, l.y - r.y, l.z - r.z)
}

func +(l: SCNVector3, r: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3(l.x + r.x, l.y + r.y, l.z + r.z)
}

func /(l: SCNVector3, r: Float) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3(l.x / r, l.y / r, l.z / r)
}
```

Detection: **(Here is the problem, I guess, in detect method)**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreML
import Vision
import SceneKit

class ObjectDetectionService {
    var mlModel = try! VNCoreMLModel(for: YOLOv3Int8LUT().model)
    //let model = try? YOLOv3Int8LUT(configuration: .init())
    
    lazy var coreMLRequest: VNCoreMLRequest = {
        return VNCoreMLRequest(model: mlModel,
                               completionHandler: self.coreMlRequestHandler)
    }()
    
    private var completion: ((Result<Response, Error>) -> Void)?
    
    func detect(on request: Request, completion: @escaping (Result<Response, Error>) -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion
        
        //let orientation = .up
        let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: request.pixelBuffer)
        
        do {
            try imageRequestHandler.perform([coreMLRequest])
        } catch {
            self.complete(.failure(error))
            return
        }
    }
}

private extension ObjectDetectionService {
    func coreMlRequestHandler(_ request: VNRequest?, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            complete(.failure(error))
            return
        }
        
        guard let request = request, let results = request.results as? [VNRecognizedObjectObservation] else {
            complete(.failure(RecognitionError.resultIsEmpty))
            return
        }
        
        guard let result = results.first(where: { $0.confidence > 0.8 }),
            let classification = result.labels.first else {
                complete(.failure(RecognitionError.lowConfidence))
                return
        }
        
        let response = Response(boundingBox: result.boundingBox,
                                classification: classification.identifier)
        
        complete(.success(response))
    }
    
    func complete(_ result: Result<Response, Error>) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.completion?(result)
            self.completion = nil
        }
    }
}

enum RecognitionError: Error {
    case unableToInitializeCoreMLModel
    case resultIsEmpty
    case lowConfidence
}

extension ObjectDetectionService {
    struct Request {
        let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer
    }
    
    struct Response {
        let boundingBox: CGRect
        let classification: String
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this warning, and How to get the camera smooth experience?

Comment: I'm using only ARKit and SceneKit, same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)` delegate method is called very frequently: many times per second. If your `classifyFrame` method is doing too much work, it will retain the `ARFrame` object until after the next frame is delivered to the delegate.

**ARKit** will warn you when too many frames are retained, typically because a queue is blocked in your delegate.